# Passing an Object as an Argument in Javascript - But not simply an Argument but an argument built from variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am passing an object to a function. Simplified example below:

```
countyInfo(sales.NY2008);
```

The object is:

```
        {countyName:"Albany",percentage:0.864789889,percentageComparison:40.18903649,sales:1222},
        {countyName:"Allegany",percentage:0.789529462,percentageComparison:27.98874729,sales:149},
        {countyName:"Broome",percentage:1.009475302,percentageComparison:63.64364553,sales:880},
        {countyName:"Cattaraugus",percentage:0.874885092,percentageComparison:41.82554597,sales:276},
        {countyName:"Cayuga",percentage:0.801267677,percentageComparison:29.89160156,sales:268},
        {countyName:"Chautauqua",percentage:0.830185925,percentageComparison:34.5794701,sales:455},
        {countyName:"Chemung",percentage:0.744919757,percentageComparison:20.75717391,sales:272},
        {countyName:"Chenango",percentage:1.191003494,percentageComparison:93.07074993,sales:242},
        {countyName:"Clinton",percentage:0.767315265,percentageComparison:24.38765663,sales:265},
        {countyName:"Columbia",percentage:0.83461736,percentageComparison:35.29783949,sales:260},
        {countyName:"Cortland",percentage:1.144086442,percentageComparison:85.46513794,sales:234},
```

It works beautifully.

Now I would like to compose this parameter from variables.

```
var getLocation = "NY";
var getYear     = "2008";
var getParameter= getLocation + getYear;
countyInfo(sales.getParameter)
```

It doesn't work as I'm passing a string. But how can this be done?

Comment: could u please show sample data of -- sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your code to use **bracket notation** to access object property instead of **dot notation**

```
var getLocation = "NY";
var getYear     = "2008";
var getParameter= getLocation + getYear;
countyInfo(sales[getParameter]);
```

Dot notation:

- Property identifies can only be alphanumeric (and _ and $)
- Propertyidentifiers cannot start with a number.
- Property identifiers cannot contain variables.
- OK — obj.prop_1, obj.prop$
- Not OK — obj.1prop, obj.prop name

Bracket notation:

- Property identifiers have to be a String or a variable that
  references a String.
- It is okay to use variables, spaces, and Strings
  that start with numbers
- OK — obj["1prop"], obj["prop name"]

For Detailed explanation refer this --

https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781

Answer (score 2):

Since `sales` seems to be an object, you can use index notation to access a member.

That is, `sales.NY2008` is equivalent to `sales["NY2008"]`.

So, simply do

```
countyInfo(sales[getLocation + getYear]);
```

Comment: whoops - was an object